# Pagination for only one specific method of ModelViewSet Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a below class

```
class Home(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = HomeSerializer
    queryset = Home.objects.all()

    @action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
    def blog_data(self, request):
        queryset = Blogs.objects.filter(identifier='blog')
        serializer = BlogDataSerializer(data=queryset, many=True)  #other serializer specific to this method
        serializer.is_valid()
        return Response(serializer.data) # need pagination here for this method only
   
   def list(self, request):
        ....
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

i have overwritten list method and i only want pagination in blog_data method to have pagination with page_size and page_number(page) to be given as query params.

example:

http://localhost:8000/home?page=1&page_size=5

how would i acheive it, i have read about pagination_class = HomePagination

but i dont want it to impact list method or any other method in this class, i only want pagination in my blog_data method

pagination.py is

```
class HomePagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        response = {
            'no_of_records': self.page.paginator.count,
            'no_of_pages': self.page.paginator.num_pages,
            'page_size': int(self.request.GET.get('page_size')),
            'page_no': self.page.number,
            'results': data
        }
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this problem by doing

```
class Home(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = HomeSerializer
    queryset = Home.objects.all()

    @action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
    def blog_data(self, request):
        self.pagination_class = HomePagination  # added this
        queryset = Blogs.objects.filter(identifier='blog')
        page_data = self.paginate_queryset(queryset) #added this
        serializer = BlogDataSerializer(data=queryset, many=True)  #other serializer specific to this method
        serializer.is_valid()
        paginated_data = self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data) # added this
        return Response(paginated_data) # need pagination here for this method only
   
   def list(self, request):
        ....
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Hope someone will get help from this in future.